# assign char string to uint32_t (only c, not c++)

Tags: c

I would like to know how I should assing a value to a uint32_t variable into the "input" variable.

see code below.

```
char *HEXlastName = "0x00D1";
uint32_t *in, input[];

char *utf8;
char word[50] = { "" };
    for(in = input; *in; ++in) {
        utf8 = to_utf8(*in);
        strcat(word, utf8);
        (void)userlog("%s:word--> %s",prc, word);
    }

char *to_utf8(const uint32_t cp)
{
    static char ret[5];
    const int bytes = codepoint_len(cp);

    int shift = utf[0]->bits_stored * (bytes - 1);
    ret[0] = (cp >> shift & utf[bytes]->mask) | utf[bytes]->lead;
    shift -= utf[0]->bits_stored;
    int i;
    for(i=1; i < bytes; ++i) {
        ret[i] = (cp >> shift & utf[0]->mask) | utf[0]->lead;
        shift -= utf[0]->bits_stored;
    }
    ret[bytes] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

I'd like to assign the value of "HEXlastName" to var.: input(uint32_t). How shoud I do it?

```
char *HEXlastName = "0x00D1";
input = HEXlastName ;   //--> This sentente is wrong. 
                       //How I could move the content of HEXlastName to input
```

Maybe it's a silly question, but I'm new in C language.

Regards

Comment: Use `sscanf` or `atoi`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Use neither, use `strtoul`.

Comment: What is the source for your input? A file (or keyboard)? Another program? Command-line arguments?

Comment: Actually what is the question here.... what's the meaning of "how I should assing a value to a uint32_t variable into the "input" variable. " Given that input is already uint32_t.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: So the question is how to convert the string `HEXlastName` to an array of `uint32_t` values, right? Is there no delimiter between the values? (i.e. every `0x` starts a new value? Are there always 5 values in the string or can the number vary? Please add all clarification to the question.

Comment: yes, Bodo. HexlastName will have one value i.e.: HexlastName="0x00D1" and I would like to put into "input" (uint32_t).

Comment: see https://ideone.com/rtRdAE

Comment: really pmg!! thank you so much!!! For me, you're a machine!!! :) Thanks, thanks!!!

Comment: Sorry pmg, one question, why in "ideone.com/rtRdAE" has size "33"?  could it be dynamic, I mean, in function of lenght var."HexlastName"? Thank you.

Comment: yes it could be dynamic; `33` was just the number that my fingers touched. And, to be safe, the code should check to not write outside the defined length. Those details I left for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the reply sir pmg give to me the answer.

I've got a var named "input"(uint32_t), and another var called "HEXlocalName"that contains an array string with unicodes (0x0000010x000002).

This routine moves the content of var "hexlocalname" into var "input" (unit32_t)

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char v[UCHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};
    v['0'] = 0;
    v['1'] = 1;
    v['2'] = 2;
    v['3'] = 3;
    v['4'] = 4;
    v['5'] = 5;
    v['6'] = 6;
    v['7'] = 7;
    v['8'] = 8;
    v['9'] = 9;
    v['a'] = v['A'] = 10;
    v['b'] = v['B'] = 11;
    v['c'] = v['C'] = 12;
    v['d'] = v['D'] = 13;
    v['e'] = v['E'] = 14;
    v['f'] = v['F'] = 15;
    char *HEXlastName = "0x00D10x00C10x00450x00C10x00D1";
    char *p = HEXlastName;
    uint32_t input[33];
    size_t n = 0;
    while (*p) {
        input[n++] = (v[(unsigned)p[2]]<<12) + (v[(unsigned)p[3]]<<8) + (v[(unsigned)p[4]]<<4) + (v[(unsigned)p[5]]);
        p += 6;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        printf("input[%d] is 0x%04X\n", k, input[k]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```